# Como pasar parámetros al intent de una notificación en Android

Tags: android, push-notification

Buen día, estoy tratando de pasar parámetros al momento de ir a una actividad cuando presiono la notificación, resulta que necesito viajar a la `Activity` de reportes pero para mostrar dichos reportes anteriormente ya he inicializado una variable luego se la paso como parámetro por lo tanto cuando hago el `intent` dando **click** a la notificación el `Activity` no me muestra nada y es obvio ya que la variable esta nula, entonces ¿Cómo podría hacer para pasar la variable como parámetro a la notificación?

El problema es que cuando ingreso a la app hago una consulta para obtener la información de usuario en el login por lo tanto si estoy fuera de la app y le doy click a la notificación, los reportes que quiero ver estarán nulos ya que no he obtenido las variables en ningún momento si no que me fui directamente a la actividad caso contrario es cuando si estoy dentro de la aplicación y le doy click a la notificación ahí si me muestra los datos correctamente ya que estoy dentro y todas las variables que paso como parámetro a las consultas si están inicializadas, bueno sin mas mostrare mi código:

Esta es mi clase FCM:

```
public class Fcm extends FirebaseMessagingService {

@Override
public void onNewToken(@NonNull String s) {
    super.onNewToken(s);
    Log.e("token","mi token es:"+s);

}

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(@NonNull RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
    String from =remoteMessage.getFrom();

    if (remoteMessage.getData().size()>0){
       String titulo=remoteMessage.getData().get("titulo");
        String detalle=remoteMessage.getData().get("detalle");
        String foto=remoteMessage.getData().get("foto");

        mayorqueoreo(titulo,detalle,foto);

    }
}

private void mayorqueoreo(String titulo, String detalle, String foto) {
    String id="mensaje";
    NotificationManager nm=(NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder=new NotificationCompat.Builder(this,id);

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel nc=new NotificationChannel(id,"nuevo", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
        nc.setShowBadge(true);
        assert nm!=null;
        nm.createNotificationChannel(nc);
    }
    try {

        Bitmap imf_foto= Picasso.get().load(foto).get();
        builder.setAutoCancel(true)
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setContentTitle(titulo)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logotaqueria)
                .setContentText(detalle)
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle()
                .bigPicture(imf_foto).bigLargeIcon(null))
                .setContentIntent(clicknoti())
                .setContentInfo("nuevo");

        Random random=new Random();
        int idNotity =random.nextInt(8000);

        assert nm !=null;
        nm.notify(idNotity,builder.build());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
}

public PendingIntent clicknoti(){
    Intent nf=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Login.class);
    nf.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    return PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,nf,0);
}
```

}

Como ven al final de la clase tengo un método llamado `PendingIntent` y como ven necesito que el **intent** lo haga a la `Activity` `obtenerReportes.class`, pero como repito los datos que le paso como parámetro a la consulta están nulos por lo tanto necesito mandar esos parámetros en el intent de la notificación y no se de que manera hacerlo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> necesito que el intent lo haga a la Activity `obtenerReportes.class`

Debes indicar en el `Intent` que defines en el `PendingIntent` que abra la clase que deseas:

```
public PendingIntent clicknoti(){
    //Intent nf=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Login.class);
    Intent nf=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), obtenerReportes.class);

    nf.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    return PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,nf,0);
}
```

> o los datos que le paso como parámetro a la consulta están nulos por
> lo tanto necesito mandar esos parámetros en el intent de la
> notificación y no se de que manera hacerlo.

Para enviar información lo debes realizar mediante el método `putExtras()` de tu `Intent`, debes crear un `Bundle` para almacenar la información que deseas enviar.
También debes definir un `requestCode` el cual se recomienda sea diferente en cada notificación.

ejemplo:

```
    private int requestCode = 0;

    public PendingIntent clicknoti(){
        //Intent nf=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Login.class);
        Intent nf=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), obtenerReportes.class);

        //Define datos a enviar.
        Bundle extras = new Bundle();
        bd.putInt("id", 12456);
        bd.putString("nombre", Jorgesys");
        nf.putExtras(extras);    

        //nf.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        //return PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,nf,0);

        return PendingIntent.getActivity(this, requestCode++, nf, 
 PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    }
```

Comment: Hola @Elenasys gracias por la respuesta solo tengo una duda de donde sale "MASK_ACTION_OPEN" Android parece no reconocerlo, es una variable o algo asi?

Comment: Ese valor no va en este caso, edite la respuesta.

Comment: Gracias por solventar la duda fijate que a pesar de averlo implementado los datos siguen siendo nulos, en este caso me gustaria entender de que manera funciona? Por ejemplo yo tengo una variable en Login por ejemplo esa variable supongamos que tiene un valor de 1 entonces si yo la trato de recuperar usando tu respuesta en que momento esa variable se recupero? si al destruir la aplicación la variable nunca se volvió a obtener? entonces por ahí va el problema yo le doy click a la notificación pero las varibles que tengo en login nunca fueron recuperadas esa es mi duda, de antemano muchas gracias

Comment: Si se abre la Activity y envias los datos almacenados en el Bundle la ùnica razòn para que lleguen vacios es que estos desde el inicio tengan ese valor, asegura que antes de enviarlos no este vacios.

Comment: Si efectivamente según lo que comentas la algunas variables no estaban siendo inicializadas ahora si ya estoy logrando adaptar mi código muchas gracias por la ayuda, Elena!!!

Comment: Excelente Adiel, saludos.